# How to select first chars with a custom word boundary?

Tags: regex, go, pcre

I've test cases with a series of words like this :

```
    {
        input:    "Halley's Comet",
        expected: "HC",
    },
    {
        input:    "First In, First Out",
        expected: "FIFO",
    },
    {
        input:    "The Road _Not_ Taken",
        expected: "TRNT",
    },
```

I want with one regex to match all first letters of these words, avoid char: "_" to be matched as a first letter and count single quote in the word.
Currently, I have this regex working on pcre syntax but not with Go regexp package : `(?<![a-zA-Z0-9'])([a-zA-Z0-9'])` 
I know lookarounds aren't supported by Go but I'm looking for a good way to do that.

I also use this func to get an array of all strings : `re.FindAllString(s, -1)`

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Using something with a [`\b`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) word boundary [like this](https://regex101.com/r/3blhbg/1) is not an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something that plays with character classes and word boundaries should suffice:

```
\b_*([a-z])[a-z]*(?:'s)?_*\b\W*
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/ONAYuS/1)

Usage:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?i)\b_*([a-z])[a-z]*(?:'s)?_*\b\W*`)
    fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString("O'Brian's dog", "$1"))

}
```

Comment: your solution returns unexpected results for the input you added in regards to OP original pcre pattern (`(?<![a-zA-Z0-9'])([a-zA-Z0-9'])`).

Comment: I can't use this regex to match all strings I need, what function I can use to get all submatches

Comment: @LoicRoux: I you want more submatches, add capture groups where you want, but give a description (with examples) of your problem(s), without this information I can't help you more.

Comment: Thanks but I've checked the doc and found different solutions working with functions like `FindSubmatch()`. Your code is working good just mine was using `findAllStrings` to get an array of all matches so your regex didn't deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

ftr, regexp less solution

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    inputs := []string{"Hallمرحباey's Comet", "First In, First Out", "The Road _Not_ Taken", "O'Brian's Dog"}
    c := [][]string{}
    w := [][]string{}
    for _, input := range inputs {
        c = append(c, firstLet(input))
        w = append(w, words(input))
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", w)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", c)
}

func firstLet(in string) (out []string) {
    var inword bool
    for _, r := range in {
        if !inword {
            if isChar(r) {
                inword = true
                out = append(out, string(r))
            }
        } else if r == ' ' {
            inword = false
        }
    }
    return out
}

func words(in string) (out []string) {
    var inword bool
    var w []rune
    for _, r := range in {
        if !inword {
            if isChar(r) {
                w = append(w, r)
                inword = true
            }
        } else if r == ' ' {
            if len(w) > 0 {
                out = append(out, string(w))
                w = w[:0]
            }
            inword = false
        } else if r != '_' {
            w = append(w, r)
        }
    }
    if len(w) > 0 {
        out = append(out, string(w))
    }
    return out
}

func isChar(r rune) bool {
    return (r >= 'a' && r <= 'z') || (r >= 'A' && r <= 'Z')
}
```

outputs

```
[][]string{[]string{"Hallمرحباey's", "Comet"}, []string{"First", "In,", "First", "Out"}, []string{"The", "Road", "Not", "Taken"}, []string{"O'Brian's", "Dog"}}
[][]string{[]string{"H", "C"}, []string{"F", "I", "F", "O"}, []string{"T", "R", "N", "T"}, []string{"O", "D"}}
```

Comment: should be, though, always write a benchmark to verify that. some things i can say upfront, if you are about to use that repetitively within a loop, adjust the signatures to take out as an input parameter and prevent further useless allocations. Allocations are the bottlenecks in those functions to get the best of this programming language. Allocations has to be considered within the scope of the overall pipeline you are writing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, precious tip for my beginner's head. I use Vs code test cases and it gives me the total execution time of a test. is it enough?

Comment: please check that answer that demonstrates how you could proceed to optimize the code https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/231000/boyer-moore-horspool-search-algorithm-in-go

Comment: Ok nice, I'm still playing with your code, good to understand...